# Swig a subset of C module while ignoring the rest of the module with other dependencies

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a my.c file that defines function "foo" and "bar", where "foo" is standalone by itself and "bar" calls other functions, say "gee", defined in a bunch of other files that I don't want to be swigged.

Now I want to use Swig to wrap "foo" from my.c, without involving other files or functions. I defined a swig interface for foo:

```
%module sample                                                                                       
%{                                                         
/* Put headers and other declarations here */                                                       
extern float    foo();                                            
%}                                                                                                             
extern float    foo();
```

I was able to build the _my.so library, but when I try to call "foo" from python, it says:

**ImportError: _my.so: undefined symbol: "gee".**

And if I remove the definition of "bar" from my.c, the whole thing works.

Is there a way to tell swig to ignore "bar" and "gee"? I even tried to add "%ignore bar;" and "%ignore gee;" in the interface, and they don't solve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional compilation in the `my.c` file:

```
foo() {
   // foo stuff
}
#if !defined(COMPILING_FOR_SWIG)
bar() {
   gee();
}
#endif
```

then when you build `my.c`, make sure you update the compiler settings to `#define COMPILING_FOR_SWIG`, e.g. usually adding the compiler option `-DCOMPILING_FOR_SWIG`. This will make sure that the compiler ignores the `bar()` function.

(Note that `COMPILING_FOR_SWIG` is a completely arbitrary name and could be changed to something else of your choosing)

Comment: That's a nice trick, thanks! Is there any other way where modifying the source file is not needed?